# Task running once a day on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I started using xamarin a few months ago, and, until now, I didn't have the need of doing something like this. 
I'm developing an app that, once a day, should run a WCF web service and verify if an information is true. If it is true, it should show a notification on the device. 
My problem is that I don't know how to perform it, i've read about backgrounding and schedule tasks, but I didn't understand well how can I perform this. How can I do it using Xamarin.Forms?

Thank you!

Comment: google  "ios/android scheduled task", "dependencyservice"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case for *Android* you can use  you can use [JobScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-job-scheduler), see this class

```
[Service(Name = "com.xamarin.samples.downloadscheduler.DownloadJob", 
         Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
public class DownloadJob : JobService
{
    public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters jobParams)
    {            
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Your periodic task here
        });

        return true;  
    }

    public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters jobParams)
    {
        //true so we re-schedule the task
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Then you can create a Factory to call this service.

```
public static class ReadLocationSchedulerFactory
    {
        public static JobInfo.Builder CreateJobBuilderUsingJobId<T>(this Context context, int jobId) where T : JobService
        {
            var javaClass = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(T));
            var componentName = new ComponentName(context, javaClass);
            return new JobInfo.Builder(jobId, componentName);
        }

    }
```

Then in your Main Activity you have to call the Factory.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {                                
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App172S.App());

            #region Scheduler

            var jobBuilder = this.CreateJobBuilderUsingJobId<ReadLocationScheduler>(152);
            //This means each 20 mins                
            jobBuilder.SetPeriodic(20 * 60 * 1000); 
            //Persists over phone restarts
            jobBuilder.SetPersisted(true); 
            //If Fails re-try each 2 mins
            jobBuilder.SetBackoffCriteria(120 * 1000, BackoffPolicy.Linear); 
            var jobInfo = jobBuilder.Build();

            var jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
            jobScheduler.Cancel(152);
            var scheduleResult = jobScheduler.Schedule(jobInfo);

            if (JobScheduler.ResultSuccess == scheduleResult)
            {
                //If OK maybe show a msg
            }
            else
            {
               //If Failed do something
            }

            #endregion

        }
```

Comment: Doesn't this update the job every time the `MainActivity` is created? In other words, if I want the job to run at 12:00, 12:20... and I open the app at 12:10, the job configuration changes to run at 12:10, 12:30...?

Answer (score 5):

For Android, a solution needs 4 components:

1. `AlarmManager` to set daily check schedule
2. `BroadCastReceiver` to receive the daily trigger and call the IntentService
3. `IntentService` to execute awaitable calls
4. `OnBootReceiver` to ensure alarms are set again after a device reboot

For iOS, you will most likely need remote push notifications.

---

Some sample code below for the Android components:

**AlarmManager - Setting the Alarm**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AlarmHelper))] // above the namespace
...
class AlarmHelper: IAlarm
{
    var now = Calendar.Instance;
    var alarmTime = Calendar.Instance;
    alarmTime.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, settings.AlarmHour); // Set Alarm start Hour
    alarmTime.Set(CalendarField.Minute, settings.AlarmMinutes); // Set Alarm Start Minutes

    if (alarmTime.Before(now))
    {
        alarmTime.Add(CalendarField.Hour, 24);
    }

    var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ScheduledAlarmHandler));
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
    var alarmManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;

    alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, alarmTime.TimeInMillis, AlarmManager.IntervalDay, pendingIntent); 
}
```

**BroadCastReceiver - Receiving the Alarm**

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
class ScheduledAlarmHandler : WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ScheduledAlarmHandler", "Starting service @" + SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime());
        Intent service = new Intent(context, typeof(WakefulAPIService)); 
        StartWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}
```

**IntentService - Executing awaitable calls**

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.test.testApp.WakefulAPIService" })]
class WakefulAPIService : IntentService
{
    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        // Your API Call code here

        Console.WriteLine("WakefulAPIService", "Completed service @ " + SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime());
        Android.Support.V4.Content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.CompleteWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

**OnBootReceiver - Ensuring alarms are set again after a device reboot**

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED", "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" })]
class OnBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("On Boot Reveiver", "Alarm Set Again after Reboot");
        var alarmHelper = new AlarmHelper();
        alarmHelper.SetAlarm();
    }

}
```

The required permissions for this to work are 'RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED' and 'WAKE_LOCK'